# Animate background color in side menu Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I would like to animate the background of my active element in side menu. I have the following html:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Dashboard</li>
      <li>Content Hub</li>
      <li>Users</li>
      <li>Sources</li>
      <li>Stories</li>
      <li (click)="toggleActive()" [ngClass]="[active ? 'active' : '']">Workshop</li>
      <li>Tags</li>
      <li>Reports</li>
      <li>Custom Categories</li>
    </ul>
```

It is just a test menu for now, I would like to animate background on click on Workshop for example,on click it gets class active = white background slides in from left to right, when loses active - slides out from right to left.

Edit: I thought about adding a transition, but how to set it to move from left to right/right -> left? CSS:

```
li {
        width: 65%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: 1s all ease-in-out;

        &.active {
          background-color: #fff;
          transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "please code this for me" service. Please describe what you have tried so far and what did not work about it.

Comment: It is a forum where you ask a question if you don't know how to do something? If i knew how to do it I wouldn't ask a question. But ok, I'll edit my post and add few ideas I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Dashboard</li>
  <li>Content Hub</li>
  <li>Users</li>
  <li>Sources</li>
  <li>Stories</li>
  <li>Tags</li>
  <li class="active">Reports</li>
  <li>Custom Categories</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
   ul li {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul li::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #5ca5f0;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li.active::before{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li.active{
  color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waq6Lq9f/2/

Comment: Pretty close, that is the effect I want to get, but on click (when the active class is added/removed). On hover I will just change the text color or something, I need this effect only when clicking on that <li>